# Is there a way to create a firebase project for my GCP project, using the CLI?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, firebase-cli

I have created a GCP project using the following command...

```
gcloud projects create project-id --name=project-name
```

When I navigate to firebase console, there is no associated project. Is there a way I can create an associate firebase project, without having to go into the web console?

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase CLI has a command `projects:addfirebase`, which add the Firebase bit to an existing Google Cloud project.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#management-commands

Comment: Can you give an example of its usage?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used the command myself as I always do these conversions in the web console. But if you're having trouble making it work, I recommend posting a new question with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Firebase CLI to add Firebase to a GCP project.

```
firebase init
```

Select "Add Firebase to existing GCP project":

[image]

Comment: I do not get the prompt you listed when I run firebase init.

Comment: @Scorb what's your Firebase CLI version? Frank's answer is a more straightforward way to do so.